# Recursive function to simplify an expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, recursion

I am in the process of writing a function that simplifies a given expression using recursion.

For example, an expression

```js
{AnyOf: ["scope1", "scope2", "scope*"]}
```

can be simplified to

```
{AnyOf: ["scope*"]}
```

using utility function `scopeCompare()` for sorting the scope array first and then `normalizeScopeSet()` which removes any duplicates present or unwanted scopes from a scope array.

I have already written a function that simplifies expression up-to this level:

```
{AnyOf: ["scope1", "scope2", "scope*"]}
```

However, if I have an expression like this:

```
{AnyOf: ["scope1", {AllOf: ["scope2a", "scope2b, "scope2*", "scope3"]}]}
```

the present function doesn't work. The above expression can be simplified to just:

```
{AnyOf: ["scope1", {AllOf:["scope2*", "scope3"]}]}
```

This is my present function:

```
const { normalizeScopeSet, scopeCompare } = require("./normalize");

exports.simplifyScopeExpression = scopeExpression => {
  if (isScope(scopeExpression)) {
    return scopeExpression;
  } else if (isAnyOf(scopeExpression)) {
    return scopeExpression;
  } else if (isAllOf(scopeExpression)) {
    return scopeExpression;
  }
};

const isScope = scopeExpression => {
  let exp = scopeExpression;
  if (typeof exp === "string") {
    return true;
  } else if (Object.keys(exp) === "AnyOf") {
    isAnyOf(scopeExpression);
  }
  else if(Object.keys(exp) === 'AllOf'){
    isAllOf(scopeExpression);
  }
};

const isAnyOf = scopeExpression => {
  let exp = scopeExpression;
  Object.keys(exp).forEach(item => {
    let expression = exp[item].sort(scopeCompare);
    exp[item] = normalizeScopeSet(expression);
  });
  return scopeExpression;
};

const isAllOf = scopeExpression => {
  let exp = scopeExpression;
  Object.keys(exp).forEach(item => {
    let expression = exp[item].sort(scopeCompare);
    exp[item] = normalizeScopeSet(expression);
  });
  return scopeExpression;
};
```

I want to modify this function so that when I pass expressions like below, I get the expected simplified expression.

1. `{AllOf: [{AllOf: ["scope1", "scope2"]}, {AllOf: ["scope2", "scope3"]}]}`
   should simplify to
   `{AllOf: ["scope1", "scope2", "scope3"]}`.
2. `{AllOf: [{AllOf: ["scope1", "scope2"]}, "scope2", "scope3"]}`
   should simplify to
   `{AllOf: ["scope1", "scope2", "scope3"]}`.
3. `{AllOf: ["scope0", {AllOf: ["scope1", {AllOf: ["scope2", {AllOf: ["scope3, {AllOf: ["scope4", "scope5"]}]}]}]}]}`
   should simplify to
   `{AllOf: ["scope0", "scope1", "scope2", "scope3", "scope4", "scope5"]}`

Notes:

The `scopeCompare` function sorts the scopes such that a scope ending with a * comes before anything else with the same prefix. For example, a* comes before a and ax.

The `normalizeScopeSet` function will normalize a scopeset. However, it requires that its input is already sorted using scopeCompare.

For example, to sort an array of scopes:

```
let scope = {AnyOf: ["scope1", "scope2", "scope*"]}
Object.keys(scope).forEach(item => {
let expression = exp[item].sort(scopeCompare);
    exp[item] = normalizeScopeSet(expression);
})
```

which gives an output

```
 {AnyOf: ["scope*"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was an interesting challenge. I've managed (I think) to get something working but with a different approach. Although there are some similarities with yours.

```js
// compress an array of patterns and strings
// remove duplicates *AND* strings matching any patterns
// compress(["scope10", "scope11", "scope11", "scope1*", "scope2", "scope2*", "scope2a"])
// => ["scope1*", "scope2*"]
//
// TODO: patterns could be optimised as well!
const compress = xs =>
  Array.of(xs)
    .map(xs => xs.filter((x, i, xs) => xs.indexOf(x) === i))
    .map(xs =>
      xs.reduce(([l, r], x) =>
        x.endsWith('*')
          ? [ l.concat(x.slice(0, -1))
            , r
            ]
          : [ l
            , r.concat(x)
            ],
        [[], []]))
    .map(([l, r]) =>
      [ ...l.map(x => x + '*')
      , ...r.filter(x => !l.some(y => x.startsWith(y)))
      ])
    .pop();

// flatten expressions that belong to the same "namespace"
// flatten_expression("AllOf", ["scope1", {AllOf: ["scope2", "scope3"]}, {AnyOf: ["scope10*", "scope20*"]}])
//=> ["scope1", "scope2", "scope3", {AnyOf: ["scope10*", "scope20*"]}]
const flatten_expression = (key, exprs) =>
  exprs.flatMap(expr =>
    typeof expr === 'string' || expr[key] === undefined
      ? expr
      : flatten_expression(key, expr[key]));

// Given an array of expressions
// compress all strings and simplify the rest
// reduce_expression(["scope1", "scope1*", {AnyOf: ["scope22", "scope2*", "scope3"]}])
// => ["scope1*", {AnyOf: ["scope2*", "scope3"]}]
const reduce_expression = xs =>
  Array.of(xs)
    .map(xs =>
      xs.reduce(([l, r], x) =>
        typeof x === 'string'
          ? [ l.concat(x)
            , r
            ]
          : [ l
            , r.concat(x)
            ],
        [[], []]))
    .map(([l, r]) =>
      [ ...compress(l)
      , ...r.map(simplify_expression)
      ])
    .pop();

// Simplify an entire object of expressions
const simplify_expression = o =>
  Array.of(o)
    .map(xs => Object.entries(xs))
    .map(xs => xs.map(([k, v]) => [k, flatten_expression(k, v)]))
    .map(xs => xs.map(([k, v]) => [k, reduce_expression(v)]))
    .map(xs => Object.fromEntries(xs))
    .pop();
    
console.log(
  simplify_expression({AnyOf: ["scope1", "scope2", "scope*"]})
)

console.log(
  simplify_expression({AnyOf: ["scope1", {AllOf: ["scope2a", "scope2b", "scope2*", "scope3"]}]})
)

console.log(
  simplify_expression({AllOf: [{AllOf: ["scope1", "scope2"]}, {AllOf: ["scope2", "scope3"]}]})
)

console.log(
  simplify_expression({AllOf: [{AllOf: ["scope1", "scope2"]}, "scope2", "scope3"]})
)

console.log(
  simplify_expression({AllOf: ["scope0", {AllOf: ["scope1", {AllOf: ["scope2", {AllOf: ["scope3", {AllOf: ["scope4", "scope5"]}]}]}]}]})
)
```